# Export label to dxf from postgresql by ogr2ogr

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, dxf

I need to export label to dxf from postgresql by ogr2ogr command, label information is text field in PG, but it is always unsuccessful, I always lose the text label information.

> ### Those commands are here:
>
> > ogr2ogr -f "DXF" "demo.dxf" "PG:host=localhost user=postgres dbname=demo pas
> >     sword=xxxx port=5432" -sql "SELECT geom, 'LABEL(f:\'Times New Roman\',s:12pt,t:\'' || text || '\')' AS OGR_STYLE FROM demo"
> >
> > ogr2ogr -select 'text' -f "DXF" "demo.dxf" "PG:host=localhost user=postgres dbname=demo pas
> >     sword=xxxx port=5432" "demo"

PG Fields are here:
[image: PG Fields And Values]

What is wrong with those commands?